# Clojure. Drop-every?

Tags: clojure, functional-programming, lazy-evaluation

Does the Clojure library have a "drop-every" type function? Something that takes a lazy list and returns a list with every nth item dropped?

Can't quite work out how to make this.

cheers

Phil

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
(defn drop-every [n xs]
  (lazy-seq
   (if (seq xs)
     (concat (take (dec n) xs)
             (drop-every n (drop n xs))))))
```

Example:

```
(drop-every 2 [0 1 2 3 4 5])
;= (0 2 4)

(drop-every 3 [0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8])
;= (0 1 3 4 6 7)
```

As a side note, `drop-nth` would be a tempting name, as there is already a `take-nth` in `clojure.core`. However, `take-nth` always returns the first item and then every nth item after that, whereas the above version of `drop-every` drops every nth item beginning with the nth item of the original sequence. (A function dropping the first item and every nth item after the first would be straightforward to write in terms of the above.)

Comment: Ah ... concat. I didn't think of that. I was trying to figure out how to take the "next item" from xs at that point, rather than just sticking them together. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If the input list length is a multiple of `n` you can use the `partition` function:

```
(defn drop-every [n lst] (apply concat (map butlast (partition n lst))))
(take 5 (drop-every 3 (range)))
; (0 1 3 4 6)
```